# Is there any option to defer the evaluation of a function call in a variadic template

Tags: c++, c++11, lazy-evaluation, variadic-templates

Suppose a variadic template:

```
void f(T value, Args... args)
```

As one of the arguments a function is passed which returns a value.

Example:   f(1, getName());

Is there a simple way to defer the evaluation of the function, so getName() is invoked inside f() and is not executed if not required.

And with a simple way I mean preferably without creating a complex calling syntax.

Comment: No, but you could use a closure...

Comment: A more complete example code would be good in a question like this.

Comment: What do you mean by "evaluated"?

Comment: I clarified the question.

Comment: @Waldorf How does `f()` know which of `args` is the function? Does it have a type that is unique among the types of the arguments? Also, how do you use `args` inside `f()`? Do you use the classical recursion pattern or something else? When and how does `f()` decide if `getName()` needs to be called or not?

Comment: You could pass `getName` and then when unpacking the arguments, if you get a function pointer or a `std::function` then call it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call f like you did in your example there is no way for f to even know that it was passed a function. Only the return value of getName is passed to f.

Like so:

```
auto x = getName();
f(1, x);
```

To only evaluate the function when needed, you can pass a function pointer:

```
f(1, getName);
```

I don't really understand the significance of variadic templates for this problem so I simplified it:

```
template <typename T, typename F>
void f(T a, F func)
{
    if (required)
        result = func();
}
```

---

If you want to pass arguments that should be used when the function is called, you can use the std::bind facilities or a lambda:

```
f(1, [&]{ return getName(arg1, arg2); });
```

Or even a case with arguments from outside and inside f:

```
template <typename T, typename F>
void f(T a, F func)
{
    if (required)
        result = func(3.0f);
}

f(1, [&](float otherArg){ return getName(arg1, arg2, otherArg); });
```

Comment: I’m assuming that OP’s case is more complex, and that `func` presumably has arguments. Still, good explanation and spot-on analysis.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks. I added a usage example for arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation, using a lambda might do the trick. It was not directly related to a variadic template. But it was the context in which it is used.